# get notified / check of end of transcoding for vimeo-api?

Tags: ruby, vimeo, vimeo-api

What's the best-practice method of checking for the release of the video after transcoding using the vimeo api?

Is there any way to set a callback url for notification?

I'll be using [this ruby wrapper](https://github.com/matthooks/vimeo/tree/master) but can make a html request if need be....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a transcoding callback (it is a planned feature), but the new API tells the transcoding status on all of your clip responses.

Look for "status", the valid fields are : available, uploading, transcoding, uploading_error, transcoding_error